# nested brace-enclosed initializer lists

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic

My code generates a syntax error with GCC :

> ```
> src/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: src/main.cpp:95:4: error:
> could not convert ‘{{"enum", E_PRINT}, {"string", "setup"}, {"object",
> {{"double", 3.1415926535897931e+0}, {"long", 1235813l}}}}’ from
> ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘Object’
> };
> ```

```
#include <cmath>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <stdlib.h>

struct NamedValueBase {

   NamedValueBase( const std::string & name ) :
      name( name )
   {}

   virtual ~ NamedValueBase( void ) {}

   std::string name;
};

template<class T>
struct NamedValue : public NamedValueBase {

   NamedValue( const std::string & name, const T & value ) :
      NamedValueBase( name ),
      value( value )
   {}

   T value;
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<NamedValueBase> sharedPair;

struct Object {

   Object( void ) {}

   Object( std::initializer_list<sharedPair > attributes ) :
      pairs( std::vector<sharedPair >(
         attributes.begin(), attributes.end() ))
   {}

   template<class T>
   void add( const std::string & name, const T & value ) {
      pairs.push_back(
         sharedPair(
            new NamedValue<T>( name, value )));
   }

   void add( sharedPair nvb ) {
      pairs.push_back( nvb );
   }

   std::vector<sharedPair > pairs;
};

template<class T>
sharedPair create( const std::string & name, T value ) {
   return sharedPair( new NamedValue<T>( name, value ));
}

inline sharedPair create(
   const std::string &                name,
   std::initializer_list<sharedPair > attributes )
{
   return sharedPair(
      new NamedValue<Object>( name, Object( attributes )));
}

enum e {
   E_PRINT
};

int main() {
   // First form: OK
   Object msg = {
      create( "enum"  , E_PRINT ),
      create( "string", "setup" ),
      create( "object", {
         create(  "double", M_PI ),
         create(  "long"  , 1235813L )}
      )
   };
   std::cout << msg.pairs.size() << std::endl;

   // Second form: error: could not convert ‘{{"enum"...5813l}}}}’ from
   // ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘Object’
   Object msg2 = {
      { "enum"  , E_PRINT },
      { "string", "setup" },
      { "object", {
         {  "double", M_PI     },
         {  "long"  , 1235813L }}
      }
   };
   std::cout << msg2.pairs.size() << std::endl;
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
// g++ -std=c++11 src/main.cpp -o object
```

Compilation and execution of the first form works well but I wish to enable the second form using parameter pack syntax i.e.

```
template<T...Args>
```

Comment: I don't have a compiler at hand right now, but I think the problem is, that the compiler can't find a valid constructor for `"object"`. You need to somehow wrap the initializer list with a helper function, or provide another constructor. A compromise would be to just use `create` inside the `"object"` list. (I think this should work...) Furthermore, you could have a look at the implementation of [github.com/nlohmann/json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json). They support your kind of behaviour for their json objects (see **Examples**).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can't be implemented with a template parameter pack because a nested initializer list is a [non-deduced context](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.deduct.type#5.5).

The trick is to implement an intermediate "builder" class using a templated constructor and a constructor accepting a list of itself to handle the nested case:

```
struct pairBuilder {
    sharedPair ptr;

    template<typename T>
    pairBuilder(const std::string & name, const T & value) : ptr(create(name, value))
    {}

    pairBuilder(const std::string & name, std::initializer_list<pairBuilder> values) :
        ptr(create(name, values))
    {}
};
```

And then accept a list of them inside `Object`:

```
struct Object {

    Object(std::initializer_list<pairBuilder> values) {
        for (auto& t : values)
            add(t.ptr);
    }

    // . . .
```

This works because in this case the normal deduction from a type happens during overload resolution, essentially "unwrapping" each braced-init-list.

Complete example:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct NamedValueBase {

    NamedValueBase(const std::string & name) :
        name(name)
    {}

    virtual ~NamedValueBase(void) {}

    std::string name;
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<NamedValueBase> sharedPair;

template<class T>
sharedPair create(const std::string & name, T value);

struct pairBuilder {
    sharedPair ptr;

    template<typename T>
    pairBuilder(const std::string & name, const T & value) : ptr(create(name, value)) {
    }

    pairBuilder(const std::string & name, std::initializer_list<pairBuilder> values) : ptr(create(name, values)) {
    }
};

template<class T>
struct NamedValue : public NamedValueBase {

    NamedValue(const std::string & name, const T & value) :
        NamedValueBase(name),
        value(value)
    {}

    T value;
};

struct Object {

    Object(void) {}

    Object(std::initializer_list<sharedPair> attributes) :
        pairs(std::vector<sharedPair >(
            attributes.begin(), attributes.end()))
    {}

    Object(std::initializer_list<pairBuilder> values) {
        for (auto& t : values)
            add(t.ptr);
    }

    template<class T>
    void add(const std::string & name, const T & value) {
        pairs.push_back(
            sharedPair(
                new NamedValue<T>(name, value)));
    }

    void add(sharedPair nvb) {
        pairs.push_back(nvb);
    }

    std::vector<sharedPair> pairs;
};

template<class T>
sharedPair create(const std::string & name, T value) {
    return sharedPair(new NamedValue<T>(name, value));
}

inline sharedPair create(
    const std::string &                name,
    std::initializer_list<pairBuilder> values)
{
    return sharedPair(
        new NamedValue<Object>(name, Object(values)));
}

enum e {
    E_PRINT
};

int main() {
    Object msg2 = {
      { "enum"  , E_PRINT },
      { "string", 2.0 },
        { "object", {
          {  "double", 3.14     },
          {  "long"  , 1235813L }}
        }
    };
    std::cout << msg2.pairs.size() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```