# Recursive data type with partly fixed types

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, recursive-datastructures

I have the following code

```
#include <string_view>
#include <utility>

namespace std
{
  template <typename T1, typename T2>
  pair(T1 t1, T2 t2) -> pair<T1, T2>;
}

template<typename ... T>
struct node {};

template<typename head_t, typename ... tail_t>
struct node<head_t, tail_t ...>
{
  node(const head_t& head, const tail_t& ... tail)
    : head(head)
    , tail(tail...)
  {}

  head_t head;
  node<tail_t ... > tail;
};

template <typename... T>
node(T... t) -> node<T...>;

int main()
{
  node n{
    std::pair{std::string_view{"a"}, int{4}},
    std::pair{std::string_view{"b"}, int{5}},
    std::pair{std::string_view{"dqwd"}, node{
      std::pair{std::string_view{"asdas"}, float{3.4}}
    }
  };
  return 0;
}
```

which I compile with

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=gnu++17 -Wl,--wrap=malloc
```

My data structure is a recursive list of a `std::pair` with the first element of type `std::string_view`.
Now I want to get rid of `std::pair` and `std::string_view` in the initalization because they will always be the same type, how can I achieve this? e.g:

```
node n{
  {"a", int{4}},
  {"b", int{5}},
  {"dqwd", node{
    {"asdas", float{3.4}}
  }
};
```

Comment: Wait, is it legal to place user-defined deduction guides into the `std` namespace?

Comment: In this case, the deduction guide for pair is not needed anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Getting rid of the `string_view`, at the very least, is pretty easy. It also has the bonus of eliminating your manipulation of the `std` namespace, which, even if it was legal, would still be making me very uncomfortable.

To be fair, your manipulation of `std` is not *that* horrible **as an example** here, because you could easily use your own `std::pair` equivalent and reach the same syntax.

```
#include <string_view>

template<typename T>
auto leaf(std::string_view s, T d) {
    return std::make_pair(s, std::move(d));
}

template<typename ... T>
struct node {};

template<typename head_t, typename ... tail_t>
struct node<head_t, tail_t ...>
{
  node(head_t head, tail_t... tail)
    : head(std::move(head))
    , tail(std::move(tail)...)
  {}

  head_t head;
  node<tail_t ... > tail;
};

template <typename... T>
node(T... t) -> node<T...>;

int main()
{
    node n{
        leaf("a", 4),
        leaf("b", 5),
        leaf("c", node{
            leaf("aaa", 12.4f)
        })
    };

  return 0;
}
```

For getting rid of leaf, The following might be applicable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51857245/4442671, but I suspect not.

As a side note, your node class could simply delegate to `std::tuple<>` which does mostly the exact same thing. This would prevent you from having to deal with recursive peeling of the arguments, and you don't even need a deduction guide:

```
template<typename... T>
struct node
{
  node(std::pair<std::string_view, T>... args)
    : childs_(std::move(args)...) {}

  std::tuple<std::pair<std::string_view, T>...> childs_;
};
```

Comment: nice idea with `std::tuple`!